# Regex - match function that calls another

Tags: regex, eclipse

So I'm trying to look for functions (among `y` and `z`) that contains a function call `a` using Eclipse search.

In this code:

```
void y ()
{
    if {    
    }
    if {
    }
}

void z ()
{
    if {
    }
    a(b(c,d,e));
    if {
    }
}
```

My Regex matches the entirety of functions `y` and `z` excluding before the function name.

```
\b(y|z) ?\(.+?(\r\n|\r|\n)(?s)\{(\r\n|\r|\n).*?((?<=\r\n|\r|\n)\})
```

What I want is a regex that matches only functions that call function `a` inside it.

I tried this but it fails:

```
\b(y|z) ?\(.+?(\r\n|\r|\n)(?s)\{(\r\n|\r|\n).*(\ba\().+?((?<=\r\n|\r|\n)\})
```

Comment: To make a suggestion, would there be anything wrong with using Eclipse's built-in ability to find _usages_ of `a()`?  If you only get a few (say < 100) results, you can pick out the cases where the parent function be `y()` or `z()`.

Comment: I'm kinda hoping I can find a solution to this as a separate problem though.

Answer (score 0):

I could achieve this through regex, and iterate over the generator object in python. May be the regex is the only thing what you need, however I'm posting the whole code here.

```
import re

mystr = '''
void y ()
{
    if {
    }
    if {
    }
}

void z ()
{
    if {
    }
    a(b(c,d,e));
    if {
    }
}

void y ()
{
    if {
    }
    a("hello");
    if {
    }
}'''

#I've assumed that the return types of both the functions as 'void'. If it is not the case, you've to add few more cases along with 'void' in the regex for other return types

#This is what you need
match = re.finditer(r'void\s*(y|z)\s*\(\s?\)\s*\{[^yz]*a((?!void).|\n|\r|\t)*', mystr)

for x in match:
    print(x.group())
```

The output I have is:

```
void z ()
{
    if {
    }
    a(b(c,d,e));
    if {
    }
}

void y ()
{
    if {
    }
    a("hello");
    if {
    }
}
```